# What is the difference between Aluminum Potassium Sulfate and Aluminum Sulfate?

Tags: photochemistry

What is the difference between Aluminum Potassium Sulfate and Aluminum Sulfate?  I mix my own photography chemistry and a formula calls for Aluminum Potassium Sulfate. My chemical supplier only has Aluminum Sulfate.  Something tells me I can't substitute the later for the former.  Help please.

---

Many thanks for the replies!  I failed to mention I'm mixing a fixing bath for films and/or papers.

Comment: What a user asks about may confuse and hide what the user wants to do and what the user needs to know to achieve his goal.  A broader context, background, purpose and relevant details could help in the delivering the optimal answer for the goal, instead of for the question.

Answer (score 4):

Photographic gelatin emulsion is relatively soft, and during the development process, soaking in water softens it further. To make it more durable, a [hardening agent](https://unblinkingeye.com/Articles/Developers/Hardeners/hardeners.html) may be added, though it is *not* required.

Two chemicals that harden the gelatin (crosslinking or "denaturing" the protein) are:

- [Formalin](https://www.fishersci.com/store/msds?partNumber=SF984&productDescription=FORMALIN%2010%25%20SOLUTION%20W/V%204L&vendorId=VN00033897&countryCode=US&language=en) (formaldehyde in water) -- toxic, and the vapor is toxic.
- Aluminum compounds, including aluminum sulfate, $\ce{Al2(SO4)3}$, and potassium aluminum sulfate, $\ce{KAl(SO4)2}$, AKA "alum" or "potassium alum". Not only are these both relatively non-toxic, but are used in cooking, and are available in [the spice section](https://www.mccormick.com/spices-and-flavors/herbs-and-spices/spices/alum) of most supermarkets. Note that there *has* been some research indicating [alum might be linked to Alzheimer's](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21157018/), yet that conclusion is debated, and alum is still used in many locales for [baking](https://www.spiceography.com/alum-powder/) and [pickling](https://www.delightedcooking.com/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-alum-for-pickling.htm). Check the price on the spice shelves -- if less than from you current source, feel free to switch.

  "**It is the $\ce{Al^3+}$ ion which does the hardening.** It really doesn't matter what salt supplies it. It can come from [aluminum sulfate](https://beta-static.fishersci.com/content/dam/fishersci/en_US/documents/programs/education/regulatory-documents/sds/chemicals/chemicals-a/S25137A.pdf) or from sodium aluminum sulfate [or from potassium aluminum sulfate, ed.]." By that logic, make the formulation with the same amount of *aluminum*, not the same *total* mass of $\ce{Al2(SO4)3}$ as $\ce{KAl(SO4)2}$.

Comment: ... and make sure you know what hydrate you have because that changes the molar mass.